# Display different frames based on logged in value in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, xampp, frame

I am creating an office management application. In this, there is admin and staff. In the Log In page based on whether it is admin or staff different frames needs to be displayed.

I used an if-else statement for this purpose.I tried to compare the value of username using get() but was unable to print its value inside the function.

Following is the code I executed.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector


class SchoolApp(tk.Tk):

    BKGR_IMAGE_PATH = 'images\\bg11.png'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("1500x750")

        main_frame = tk.Frame(self,width=200,height=50,highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        main_frame.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='True')

        main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.bkgr_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.BKGR_IMAGE_PATH)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (HomePage,LogIn,AdminPage,StaffPage):
            frame = F(main_frame, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        self.show_frame(HomePage)

    def show_frame(self,container):
        frame = self.frames[container]
        frame.tkraise()

class BasePage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        label_bkgr = tk.Label(self, image=controller.bkgr_image)
        label_bkgr.place(x=0,y=0)  # Center label w/image.


class HomePage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        home_frame = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white")
        home_frame.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        self.label_title = tk.Label(home_frame, text="Office Management System", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=0)

        staff_frame = tk.Frame(home_frame, width=100, height=50)
        staff_frame.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.staff_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\staff1.png")
        self.staff_Image_Pack = tk.Label(staff_frame, image=self.staff_Image)
        self.staff_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.staff_button = tk.Button(home_frame, text="Staff", width=20, font=("Helvetica", 12),command = lambda: controller.show_frame(LogIn))
        self.staff_button.grid(row=60, column=0, pady=20)

        admin_frame = tk.Frame(home_frame, width=100, height=50)
        admin_frame.grid(row=55, column=10, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.Admin_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\admin1.png")
        self.Admin_Image_Pack = tk.Label(admin_frame, image=self.Admin_Image)
        self.Admin_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.admin_button = tk.Button(home_frame, text="Admin", width=20, font=("Helvetica", 12),command = lambda: controller.show_frame(LogIn))
        self.admin_button.grid(row=60, column=10, pady=20)

class LogIn(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        login_window = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white")
        login_window.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        login_img_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=200, height=50, background="white")
        login_img_frame.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
        self.login_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\lock3.png")
        self.login_Image_Pack = tk.Label(login_img_frame, image=self.login_Image)
        self.login_Image_Pack.grid()

        login_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=100, height=50, background="white", highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        login_frame.grid(row=55, column=10, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.label_title = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Log In", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_username = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_username.grid(row=50, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=50, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_password = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_password.grid(row=60, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=60, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        #print(self.entry_username.get())

        if(self.entry_username.get()=="admin"):
            self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda:[self.submit(),controller.show_frame(AdminPage)],font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
            self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
            self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda:[self.submit(),controller.show_frame(StaffPage)],font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
            self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)

    def submit(self):

        self.u_name = self.entry_username.get()
        self.p_word = self.entry_password.get()

        employee = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="edatabase")
        cursor_variable = employee.cursor()

        cursor_variable.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('" + self.u_name + "','" + self.p_word + "')")
        employee.commit()

        employee.close()

class AdminPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        admin_window = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white")
        admin_window.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        self.label_title_admin = tk.Label(admin_window, text="Welcome Admin", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title_admin.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='W')

        admin_add = tk.Frame(admin_window, width=100, height=50)
        admin_add.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.admin_add_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\add3.png")
        self.admin_add_Image_Pack = tk.Label(admin_add, image=self.admin_add_Image)
        self.admin_add_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.add_staff_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text="Add Staff", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.add_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=0, pady=20)

        admin_delete = tk.Frame(admin_window, width=100, height=50)
        admin_delete.grid(row=55, column=10, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.admin_delete_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\delete2.png")
        self.admin_delete_Image_Pack = tk.Label(admin_delete, image=self.admin_delete_Image)
        self.admin_delete_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.delete_staff_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text="Remove Staff", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.delete_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=10, pady=20)

        admin_select = tk.Frame(admin_window, width=100, height=50)
        admin_select.grid(row=55, column=20, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.admin_select_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\select2.png")
        self.admin_select_Image_Pack = tk.Label(admin_select, image=self.admin_select_Image)
        self.admin_select_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.select_staff_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text="Select Staff", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.select_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=20, pady=20)

        admin_display = tk.Frame(admin_window, width=100, height=50)
        admin_display.grid(row=55, column=30, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.admin_display_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\display1.png")
        self.admin_display_Image_Pack = tk.Label(admin_display, image=self.admin_display_Image)
        self.admin_display_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.display_staff_button = tk.Button(admin_window, text="Display Staff", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.display_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=30, pady=20)

class StaffPage(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):

        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        staff_window = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white", highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        staff_window.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        self.label_title_staff = tk.Label(staff_window, text="Welcome Staff", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title_staff.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='W')

        staff_register = tk.Frame(staff_window, width=100, height=50)
        staff_register.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.register_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\register1.png")
        self.register_Image_Pack = tk.Label(staff_register, image=self.register_Image)
        self.register_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.register_staff_button = tk.Button(staff_window, text="Add Details", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.register_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=0, pady=20)

        staff_display = tk.Frame(staff_window, width=100, height=50)
        staff_display.grid(row=55, column=30, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.staff_display_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\display1.png")
        self.staff_display_Image_Pack = tk.Label(staff_display, image=self.staff_display_Image)
        self.staff_display_Image_Pack.grid()

        self.display_staff_button = tk.Button(staff_window, text="Display Details", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.display_staff_button.grid(row=60, column=30, pady=20)


app = SchoolApp()
app.mainloop()
```

This is my log in page code

```
class LogIn(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        login_window = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white")
        login_window.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        login_img_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=200, height=50, background="white")
        login_img_frame.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
        self.login_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\lock3.png")
        self.login_Image_Pack = tk.Label(login_img_frame, image=self.login_Image)
        self.login_Image_Pack.grid()

        login_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=100, height=50, background="white", highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        login_frame.grid(row=55, column=10, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.label_title = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Log In", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_username = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_username.grid(row=50, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=50, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_password = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_password.grid(row=60, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=60, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        #print(self.entry_username.get())

        if(self.entry_username.get()=="admin"):
            self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda:[self.submit(),controller.show_frame(AdminPage)],font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
            self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)
        else:
            self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda:[self.submit(),controller.show_frame(StaffPage)],font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
            self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)

    def submit(self):

        self.u_name = self.entry_username.get()
        self.p_word = self.entry_password.get()

        employee = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="edatabase")
        cursor_variable = employee.cursor()

        cursor_variable.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('" + self.u_name + "','" + self.p_word + "')")
        employee.commit()

        employee.close()
```

I have no errors. Whether it's admin or staff the else condition works and staff page is getting displayed.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please simplify the code and remove all of the non necessary widgets? We really don't want to debug that much code.

Comment: Your attempt to get the value with `.get()` in `__init__` happens about a millisecond after you create the `Entry` widget. The user won't have even seen the UI, much less had a chance to enter any data.

Comment: @TheLizzard I have edited the question.. I hope this is convenient for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the class LogIn(BasePage) as follows and it works. I changed the `submit(self)` to `submit(self,controller)`.

Thank you everyone for your response.

```
class LogIn(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        super().__init__(parent, controller)

        login_window = tk.Frame(self, width=200, height=100, background="white")
        login_window.grid(row=50, column=150, padx=300, pady=100)

        login_img_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=200, height=50, background="white")
        login_img_frame.grid(row=55, column=0, padx=50, pady=50)
        self.login_Image = tk.PhotoImage(file="images\\lock3.png")
        self.login_Image_Pack = tk.Label(login_img_frame, image=self.login_Image)
        self.login_Image_Pack.grid()

        login_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, width=100, height=50, background="white", highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
        login_frame.grid(row=55, column=10, padx=50, pady=50)

        self.label_title = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Log In", font=("Helvetica", 40), bg="white")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_username = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Username", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_username.grid(row=50, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_username = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_username.grid(row=50, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.label_password = tk.Label(login_frame, text="Password", font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.label_password.grid(row=60, column=20, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(login_frame, width=15, font=("Helvetica", 20), bd=3)
        self.entry_password.grid(row=60, column=30, padx=10, pady=10)

        #print(self.entry_username.get())

        self.login_button = tk.Button(login_frame, text="Log In", command=lambda:self.submit(controller),font=("Helvetica", 20), bg="white")
        self.login_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)


    def submit(self,controller):

        self.u_name = self.entry_username.get()
        self.p_word = self.entry_password.get()

        employee = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="edatabase")
        cursor_variable = employee.cursor()

        cursor_variable.execute("INSERT INTO login VALUES ('" + self.u_name + "','" + self.p_word + "')")
        employee.commit()

        employee.close()

        if (self.u_name== "admin"):
            controller.show_frame(AdminPage)
        else:
            controller.show_frame(StaffPage)
```